# Something wrong with JDialog

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swing, jdialog

I'm currently trying to print a message to the user in a program I'm making, but somehow the result is not what I expected. I used, as an example, Oracles sugestion for a message dialog, wich is:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
```

I get this (notice the missing dot at the end and the missing K in the button):

[image: Ouput of the Program]

Is it possible that this is something wrong with my JDK or JRE? Also, I don't know if it can be important or not, but I'm programming this on the eclipse platform, running on windows 7.

**Edit number1:**
As sugested, I tried with a simpler example and got the same result. Here is the code for the simpler example:

```
public class SampleGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit number2:** To make things weirder, I seem to be able to avoid this outcome by connecting my laptop to an outlet. This seems tremendously stupid, and I can only assume it is something wrong with my computer. What could make this happen?

Update on edit2: It does not seem to work every time. For reasons I cannot explain, I have tried a few minutes ago with my laptop charging and I'm getting the same results.

**Edit number3:** I have configured a dual-boot with windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04 and I am also unable to reproduce the error on ubuntu.

Comment: Whenever I think that there's something wrong with Java, 99.9% of the time the error is in my **understanding** of Java and not Java itself. I'd give you the same odds. Please create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let's see for ourselves.

Comment: I believe this sufices as a minimal example, as I did not got the chance to write much more code than this. Nonetheless I will try with something even more simpler and then edit the question. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the effect illustrated.

Comment: It seems that Swing calculates the size of the dialog wrongly. Can you manually resize the dialoue and make the missing characters appear? My guess is that you have somehow "magnified" your desktop (for larger fonts on monitors with super-high resolution) and that Swing can not handle this well.

Comment: @tobias_k: It would appear so, but I have not modified my desktop, at all (at least as far as I'm aware).
Can you provide a code example showing how to rezise the dialog when it is created via `JOption.showMessageDialog(null,"Message");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to amend the question first, because I *recognize* that dialog box, and the source can help explain where you got the idea to code this the way you did:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Now, the impulse to put `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` into an `invokeLater` is correct, even though the example program doesn't; the example program spawns the dialog in response to a `MouseEvent`/`ActionEvent`, so thread safety was ensured. Your code starts from a static context on a new thread, so the `invokeLater` was right.

What happens next is interesting because swing might be causing the problem it's meant to avoid: The current `EventDispatchThread` stalls and a new event pump begins to handle events on the dialog. Since all drawing also happens on the EDT, I have a sneaking suspicion that either a `paint` or a `layout` is getting lost on your original EDT.

Instead of calling the convenience method, try this intermediate version:

```
public class SampleGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
                JDialog generatedDialog = optionPane.createDialog("Message");
                generatedDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above should be equivalent in every way
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JOptionPane-source.html
(line 926, with a call to line 368)

except that now you have a JDialog that you can poke with `repaint`, `invalidate`, or `pack` to make sure everything displays properly.

Comment: I haven't used windows for a few weeks now and since I've changed I never saw this error again. More, even while on windows I experimented with Swing and didn't get a single graphical "bug", so this was very strange for me. I did however accept your answer because I do believe that you're right, although I am not capable of reproducing the effect again. 
+1 For teaching me how to have a pokeable JDialog. It should prove itself useful soon!